# Fastapi - How to ignore optional arguments passed to my function?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm creating an API (FastAPI) that can create database in my catalog. The python function that creates the db takes few arguments. Some are optional (like Description, LocationUri, Parameters) and some are mandatory (CatalogId, etc). I created a Pydantic model that defines these arguments.

```py
class createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Description: Optional[str] = None
    LocationUri: Optional[str] = None
    Parameters: Optional[dict] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode =  True
```

```py
class createGlueDatabase(BaseModel):
    CatalogId: str
    DB_input: createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput

    class Config:
        orm_mode =  True
```

In the above, the catalog id is the only mandatory argument, and the rest are optional. So when the optional parameters are ignored or not provided in the swagger, those values are coming in as "None" to the function. This results in the function failing.

I tried doing the following in my code:

- Added `response_model_exclude_none=True` to my router function that receives the input argument, but this didnt help.
- Tried to create everything (other than the catalog id) as optional, still no success.

Can someone help me understand, how to ignore None being sent to my python function? Please let me know if you need any other details. Thanks in advance.

Tried using Pydantic models:

```py
class createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Description: Optional[str] = None
    LocationUri: Optional[str] = None
    Parameters: Optional[dict] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode =  True
```

```py
class createGlueDatabase(BaseModel):
    CatalogId: str
    DB_input: createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput

    class Config:
        orm_mode =  True
```

Tried adding additional args like `response_model_exclude_none=True`, but didnt work.

Comment: I think i found the solution: I need to add `exclude_none=True` to my arguments. If you have any other solutions, please share.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you're calling the function as well, but `exclude_none` with `dict` or similar is probably the way to go. `response_model_exclude_none` is only relevant to the response - i.e. what is being returned to the client that made the request, not for how the request is handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more code for a better answer?

I think that you need to ignore None in your my python function. This is normal practice. See for example https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#use-the-model.

```py
class createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Description: Optional[str] = None
    LocationUri: Optional[str] = None
    Parameters: Optional[dict] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode =  True


app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/my_route")
async def create_item(input_data: createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput):
    # here
    ...
```

If you pass the input to the POST with the following body

```json
{
  "Name": "MyName"
}
```

then in the place where the comment `# here` we have

```py
createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput(Name='MyName', Description=None, LocationUri=None, Parameters=None)
```

It is serialization of pydantic.

For the `Parameters` field you can to add the following initial value

```py
class createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Description: Optional[str] = None
    LocationUri: Optional[str] = None
    Parameters: Optional[dict] = Field(default_factory=dict)

    class Config:
        orm_mode =  True
```

Then we will have

```py
createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput(Name='MyName', Description=None, LocationUri=None, Parameters={})
```

where `createGlueDatabaseDatabaseInput.Parameters` is empty dict.